# Ubuntu installer keeps slowing down and freezing

Tags: system-installation, 22.04, hardware, compatibility, 23.10

I'm trying to dual boot Windows 11 and Ubuntu (The desktop version).  Every time I get to the installer, usually at the "Updates and other software" section, it always freezes whenever I click Next, even if I uncheck everything about updating and other software.

I've tried 23.10 to see if that would fix anything (I was trying to install 22.04), but that would hang too, and when I did the "Try Ubuntu" option, literally no application would open at all.  Is it because I have NVIDIA hardware, or is my computer just incompatible?

Here are my specs.

Motherboard: Gigabyte H410M-S2H
RAM: 16gb
CPU: Intel i3-10300 @ 3.70GHz 3696 Mhz, 4 Cores, 8 Processors
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GT 710

EDIT: I've tried "Safe Graphics".  Not only does the installer not show at all, but it gives me a "FAILED" error saying it can't load the installer.

EDIT 2: I tried again with 23.10, and the installer kept randomly closing by itself, leaving me with a blank screen and no working applications to figure out what was wrong.  I tried updating the installer when it gave me the option, and it gave me a "system program problem" error and told me to restart the installer.  I did that, and it just closed.